# How to generate sources in an sbt plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to generate some sources as described in [Generating files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html).

When I put the following in my `build.sbt`, everything works:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val file = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "demo" / "Test.scala"
  IO.write(file, """object Test extends App { println("Hi") }""")
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

But when I attempt to do the same thing in a plugin, the task never runs:

```
object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
      val file = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "demo" / "Test.scala"
      IO.write(file, """object Test extends App { println("Hi") }""")
      Seq(file)
    }.taskValue
  )
}
```

Everything else I put in my plugin seems to work fine, but the source file is never generated.

Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to load your plugin after the `JvmPlugin`, which resets `sourceGenerators` in `projectSettings` (see `sbt.Defaults.sourceConfigPaths`).

You can do that by adding it as a requirements to your plugin, e.g.

```
override def requires = JvmPlugin
```

Your complete example should look as follows:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import plugins._

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = JvmPlugin
  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
      val file = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "demo" / "Test.scala"
      IO.write(file, """object Test extends App { println("Hi") }""")
      Seq(file)
    }.taskValue
  )
}
```