# How do I modify sourceGenerators in Compile from an AutoPlugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, code-generation, sbt-plugin

I'm writing a code generation plugin for sbt using the new AutoPlugin mechanism. I need to modify the `sourceGenerators in Compile` setting but somehow it does not work when I do it from the plugin. After calling compile, nothing is printed on the screen.

However, if I take the line `sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (mySourceGenerator in Compile)` and move it to the `build.sbt` of the project suddenly the `sourceGenerators in Compile`setting is modified and when I run the compile task the message is written to the screen.

Is there something I'm missing there? The code of the plugin is here:

```
package net.lopezbobeda.plugin

import sbt._
import Keys._
import java.io.{ File, Writer }

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  // by defining autoImport, the settings are automatically imported into user's `*.sbt`
  object autoImport {
    // configuration points, like the built-in `version`, `libraryDependencies`, or `compile`
    lazy val mySourceGenerator = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Generate")

    // default values for the tasks and settings
    lazy val baseXtendPluginSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
      mySourceGenerator in Compile := {
        val s: TaskStreams = streams.value
        s.log.info("Generating! "  + sourceManaged.value)
        Nil
      },
      sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (mySourceGenerator in Compile) // if I put this line in build.sbt everything works as expected.
      )

  }

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  import autoImport._

  override val projectSettings = baseXtendPluginSettings


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the JVM plugin resets the sourceGenerators setting. The solution is just to add:

```
override def requires = JvmPlugin
```

I found the solution in this other question:

[How to generate sources in an sbt plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724406/how-to-generate-sources-in-an-sbt-plugin?rq=1)